# How to SUM column 1 and select column 2 by condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I've stuck with how to sum column `A` and select column `B` with a condition if column `B >= 50` select this row id.

Example Table Like this

`+----+-----------+---------+
| ID | PRICE     | PERCENT |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 |  5        |    5    | 
|  2 |  18       |    20   |
|  3 |  7        |    50   |
|  4 |  16       |    56   |
|  5 |  50       |    87   |
|  6 |  17       |    95   |
|  7 |  40       |    107  |
+----+-----------+---------+`

```
SELECT ID, SUM(PRICE) AS PRICE, PERCENT FROM Table
```

Column `ID` and `PERCENT`, I want to select from a row with `PERCENT >= 50`

The result should be

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Why `ID` is equal to `4`? Why the `PERCENT` is `56`?

Answer (score 1):

Try below query:

```
declare @tbl table(ID int, PRICE int, [PERCENT] int);
insert into @tbl values
(1, 5, 5),
(2, 18, 20),
(3, 7, 50),
(4, 16, 56),
(5, 50, 87),
(6, 17, 95),
(7, 40, 107);

select top 1 ID,
             (select sum(PRICE) from @tbl) PRICE,
             [PERCENT]
from @tbl
where [PERCENT] > 50
```

Answer (score 1):

You could include the total in a subquery in the `SELECT` clause of your query like this:

```
SELECT
    [ID],
    (SELECT SUM([PRICE]) FROM T) AS [PRICE],
    [PERCENT]
FROM
    T
WHERE
    [PRICE] >= 50
```

However, it remains unclear which of the five valid records should be picked. You indicated it should be the record where `PERCENT` has value 56, but IMHO value 50 would be possible too, just like 87, 95, and 107 (?). It is unclear why you pick value 56 as the correct one. If it doesn't matter, you could use `TOP (1)` in the `SELECT` clause, but if it does matter, you should extend the `WHERE` clause with appropriate conditions/filters.

Mixing aggregate data from groups back with individual elements/records like this is often fuzzy. I consider it to be a "code smell" and here in your question on StackOverflow, it might indicate an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Anyway, these query results might get misinterpreted quite easily if you are not careful. Always remember that such aggregated data in the result (in this case the `PRICE` field) has practically nothing to do with the detail data in the result (in this case the `ID` and `PERCENT` fields). Unless you want to combine your aggregate data with your detail data (in a calculation for example), but you do not indicate you want anything like that in your question...

Answer (score 0):

you can do this Trick to have a result of 2 queries in 1 query:

```
 select ID as ID,T.[PERCENT] AS B, 0 as sumA
 from Table_1 as T
 where T.[PERCENT]>=50
 union All
 select 0 as ID,0 AS B, sum(t.[PRICE]) as sumA
 from Table_1 as T
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure why you need this but certainly, You can Archive Above Output using below query

**Sample Data**

```
declare  @data table
(Id int, Price int, [Percent] int)
insert @data
VALUES (1,5,5),           
      (2,18,20),
      (3,7,50),
      (4,16,56),
      (5,50,87),
      (6,17,95),
      (7,40,107)
```

**Query**

```
select top 1 ID,  (select sum(price) from @data) as Price, [Percent ]
from  @data
where [Percent ] >50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
SELECT TOP (1) [ID],  SUM(PRICE) OVER (),  [PERCENT] 
FROM @tbl
ORDER BY CASE WHEN [PERCENT] > 50 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, [ID];
```

I am using `OVER` clause in order to extract/read data from the table only once - one table scan.